# Custom icon and text in Intent Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to allow user to pick an image or take a new photo. I've implemented a custom camera activity.

When the user click on a button, an Intent Chooser is launched, asking among apps that allow to pick an image. Among them, I've added an intent that start my camera activity in order to take a new picture.

```
    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    pickImageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file.getAbsolutePath());

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickImageIntent, "");
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
```

The problem is that among the icons in the dialog of the Intent Chooser there is also the icon of my app and its name, because of the camera intent.

[image]

Is it possible to customize the icon and the label instead of using the app ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html, note "label" and "icon" attributes

Comment: thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I don't want to change the icon and the name of my app. Just change them in the dialog. Like put an icon of a camera and "Photo" as label.

Comment: these attributes apply to Activity, not the whole applicarion

Comment: ah sorry... I didn't note it. I'm checking now.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the name and icon in your activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Like this:

```
<activity android:label="Camera" android:icon="@drawable/myCameraIcon" android:name=".CameraActivity" />
```